# nvidia resolution mess after sleep mode

Tags: nvidia, suspend, display, display-resolution

I installed Ubuntu 23.10 on a laptop Legion Pro 5 (`16IRX8`). It has a `GeForce RTX 4070 Max-Q` GPU.

It's connected to an external display Samsung 49" CRG90 DQHD Curved 120Hz (`LC49RG90SSUXEN`)

When I start the laptop, the display is detected properly and I can set the external display to `5120x1440 120Hz` and all looks fine.

But if it goes to sleep mode or the display is off after few minutes, when it wakes up, the display is configured as `3840x1080 120Hz` and I'm not able to change back to `5120x1440 120Hz` because for that resolution **the only option is 100Hz or 59.98Hz**.

Any idea or guidense to find where is the problem?

```
~ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic
```

```
~ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  535.154.05  Thu Dec 28 15:37:48 UTC 2023
GCC version:
```

Note: Logout and login allows me to select the right resolution again.